Arrange multiple application processes in a single Azure Data Factory
I am kind of new to Azure data factory. For each application project I implemented, we used to create a standard alone ADF.
However, as I had some experience in MSSQL SSIS package, to my knowledge, one SSIS service instance can include multiple project folders, so I am wondering if I can place multiple application projects' processes in one single ADF instance?
What will be the pros and cons?

